# Proc Report Color Coding with Traffic Lights instead of highlighting entire cell?

Tags: excel, sas, enterprise-guide, proc-report

I have a report we run in SAS and format in Excel that has traffic color coding based on Excel formulas. I'd really like to just have everything created in SAS, so I have been using PROC REPORT to create my tables. However I am not sure if the traffic lights (like below) can be used in SAS, and they're pretty adamant I need the traffic lights (or even arrows), but **not** highlight the entire cell or the text. I am using SAS EG 9.4. Should I use an image to have the circles populate in another column? Or is there a nifty way to do this?

[image: Example of traffic light coloring]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  The how is a bit long for a Stack Overflow question.  Google returns a number of results.  This SGF paper does a good job of covering the basics  http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/290-2011.pdf

Comment: I think you could easily put the detail into an answer - the actual detail of using `preimage` is pretty short.  Otherwise this isn't really an answer, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

I do not have experience in SAS.  I simply recorded this in Excel.  This is the relevant code to create the stoplight conditional formatting.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("G4:G9").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .ReverseOrder = False
        .ShowIconOnly = False
        .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3TrafficLights1)
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(2)
        .Type = xlConditionValuePercent
        .Value = 33
        .Operator = 7
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(3)
        .Type = xlConditionValuePercent
        .Value = 67
        .Operator = 7
    End With
End Sub
```